# Any Tournament APIs out there?

Tags: php, javascript, tournament

Are there any APIs for helping running tournaments that can draw brackets, count scores, etc? Something on PHP/javascript would be nice but I can't find any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the process of building one right now.

Mine supports *Round-Robin*, *Single-Elimination*, and *Boil-Off* tournaments!  I am working on Double Elimination as we speak.  [I actually need to get it done for an event we have this weekend. ;)]

It also supports the folowing scoring modes: Highest Score (Team Sports), Lowest Score (Golf, etc.), Highest Time (King-of-the-Hill), and Lowest Time (Racing, etc.).

http://tournaments.codeplex.com

---

Here it is in action:

http://lanlordz.net/Events/ViewTournament/4

As you can tell, it was optimized for LAN parties.

It is not in PHP; but, I would encourage a port to PHP.

Comment: Absolutely.  MIT license.  I just uploaded it to codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tourneylogic.com/products/bracketcontrol/default.aspx

Not free though

Comment: That is not actually a tournament API, but a .NET web control for submitting fantasy brackets. (and displaying results)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty useful [jquery plugin](http://frank-mich.com/jQuery/) that draws a binary tree which can be used for building tourney brackets.